# DNS lookup using host IP not working

Tags: dns, named

I have set up a master DNS server using isc-bind. My problem is that when I try to look up hostnames from the same computer, it works when using localhost but not when I use the IP of the host.

This gives the correct answers:-

```
dig @localhost www.google.com
```

But this says "connection timed out; no servers could be reached"

```
dig @192.168.0.1 www.google.com
```

Here's my resolv.conf

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

And when I run ping to 192.168.0.1, I get replies. What am I doing wrong here ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your instance of BIND is probably only listening on the loopback interface (127.0.0.1) and won't answer when addressed by an IP address that's associated with a real physical interface (your 192.168.0.1)

Look in your `named.conf` file for the `listen-on` directive.  You may also need to change the `allow-query` ACL.